# How {props.children} is different from normal objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React with the help of a crash course. I was learning about nested components and props where I have some confusion. I was making a small comment section.
**Like this**[image]
Here I have used two components the **CommentDetail.js** where user's name,image and comment will display and **ApprovalCard.js** which is for approving the comment made by user(Approve/Reject).
CommentDetail here is child component of ApprovalCard here.
The instructor told that when we nest the components the parent component receive object in props.And this props contains a property `children` which we can render.What I am not understanding is when I `console.log(props)` in **ApprovalCard.js** children itself is an object inside props.As object can not render in JSX than how `{props.children}` is working here ?
**Index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import faker from 'faker';
import CommentDetail from './CommentDetail';
import ApprovalCard from './ApprovalCard';

const App = () => {
    return  (
            <div className='ui comments'>
            <ApprovalCard>
                <CommentDetail author='Maximillian' timesAgo = 'Today at 4:00PM' comment = 'Nice blog post!'
                    image = {faker.image.avatar()}/>
            </ApprovalCard>
            <ApprovalCard>
                <CommentDetail author='Kishan' timesAgo = 'Today at 1:00AM' comment = 'Touched every important point.'
                    image = {faker.image.avatar()}/>
            </ApprovalCard>
            <ApprovalCard>
                <CommentDetail author='Punit' timesAgo = 'Today at 6:32PM' comment = 'Far better than any other article I have come across'
                    image = {faker.image.avatar()}/>
            </ApprovalCard>
            </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector('#root'));
```

**CommentDetail.js**

```js
import React from 'react';


const CommentDetail = (props)=>
{
    console.log(props);
    return (
            <div className="comment">
                <a className='avatar'>
                    <img alt="avatar" src={props.image}/>
                </a>
                <div className='content'>
                    <a className='author'>{props.author}</a>
                    <div className='metadata'>
                        <span className='date'>{props.timesAgo}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='text'>
                        {props.comment}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
};

export default CommentDetail;
```

**ApprovalCard.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

const ApprovalCard = (props) => {
    console.log(props.children);
    return (
        <div className = "ui card">
            <div className="content">{props.children}</div>
            <div className="extra content">
                <div className="ui two buttons">
                    <div className="ui basic green button">Approve</div>
                    <div className="ui basic red button">Reject</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ApprovalCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is containing the following `<ApprovalCard>` component which has one component inside which is the `<CommentDetail>` child:

```
<ApprovalCard>
    <CommentDetail author='Maximillian' timesAgo = 'Today at 4:00PM' comment = 'Nice blog post!' image = {faker.image.avatar()} />
</ApprovalCard>
```

So technically `props.children` will be the `<CommentDetail>` component which can be rendered as JSX in the following statement because it is not just a simple object:

```
<div className="content">{props.children}</div>
```

From the [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) documentation check especially the [containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) section which states:

> Some components don’t know their children ahead of time. This is especially common for components like Sidebar or Dialog that represent generic “boxes”.
>
> We recommend that such components use the special children prop to pass children elements directly into their output.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You said `Your code is containing the following <ApprovalCard> component which has inside the <CommentDetail> child`.I thought its the otherwise.

Comment: @user239887 I mean the `<CommentDeatail>` is inside `<ApprovalCard>`, let correct that sentence.